# How to zip a list of files in Linux

Tags: bash, zip

I have many files I need to zip into a single directory. I don't want to zip all the files in the directory, but only ones matching a certain query.

I did

```
grep abc file-* > out.txt
```

to make a file with all the instances of "abc" in each file. I need the files themselves.
How can I tell bash to zip only those files?

Comment: Wildcards does not work? Why? If I can ask...

Comment: @jherran I don't want to zip all the files in the directory, only ones matching a certain query.  I did `grep abc file-* > out.txt` to make a file with all the *instances* of "abc" in each file.  I need the files themselves.

Comment: What @jherran means is `zip ZipFile.zip file-*`, which is the obvious way to do it. You would need an intermediate file only if you were using a complex `find` or a concatenation of file lists from different searches.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Very simple:

```
zip archive -@ < out.txt
```

That is, if your `out.txt` file contains one filename per line. It will add all the files from `out.txt` to one archive called `archive.zip`.

The `-@` option makes `zip` read from STDIN.

If you want to skip creating a temporary `out.txt` file, you can use `grep`'s capability to print filenames, too. `-r` enables recursive search (might not be necessary in your case) and `-l` prints only filenames:

```
grep -rl "abc" file-* | zip archive -@
```

Comment: Works nicely, except I have a list file where there are spaces in file names. I tried both escaping them with `\` and not escaping them, once in quotes and once without quotes around the file name (one line - one file name). Nothing worked so far.

Comment: I made it work with ` \ ` escaped spaces and no quotes in the file and the following: `cat out.txt | while read line ; do xargs zip archive.zip $line ; done`

Comment: if you want to zip files with similar names you could try `zip archive.zip $(ls common_name*)`

Comment: @chepe263 This breaks if files have spaces in their path. It's generally discouraged to parse ls output.

Comment: For anyone else on a mac who wound up here courtesy of search engine indexing, the `-@` option syntax works fine as of 10.16, even though the man page still includes language about `not on MacOS`

Answer (score 5):

Alternatives to the accepted answer, from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/652892/create-zip-based-on-contents-of-a-file-list):

```
cat out.txt | zip -@ zipfile.zip
cat out.txt | zip -@ - > zipfile.zip
zip zipfile.zip $(cat out.txt) -r
zip zipfile.zip -r . -i@out.txt
```

Comment: I like the first one.  Worked well for me.

The last one did not seem to work well - took too long, so I ctrl-c'd out of it.