# Have "zip" read a text file containing paths of files to zip

Tags: zip

Is there a way to have the `zip` command read a file (say, `~/tmp/FilesToZip.txt`) to obtain the paths of the file to zip up?  Ideally, `zip` will intrepret each line as a file path, which can include spaces.  My current verbose way of getting this effect is

```
cat ~/tmp/FilesToZip.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | \
   xargs -0 zip -@ ~/tmp/ZipFileName.zip
```

I found an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/834959/how-to-zip-a-list-of-files-in-linux).  At least one answer seems to indicate that it should be able to handle file names/paths that contains spaces, but some comments indicate otherwise.  It seems that if `zip` is made to read file names/paths from `stdin`, then it properly interprets each line as a file path, regardless of whether it contains spaces.  Here is what I found to work:

```
# Make some folders & files whose names contain spaces
$ mkdir "Subfolder A"
$ mkdir "Subfolder B"
$ ls > Subfolder\ A/File.txt
$ ls > Subfolder\ B/File.txt
$ find Subfolder\ [AB]/* -type f > FilePaths.txt
$ cat FilePaths.txt

   Subfolder A/File.txt
   Subfolder B/File.txt

$ zip Test.zip -i@FilePaths.txt  #  DOESNT WORK

   zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)

$ zip Test.zip -@ < FilePaths.txt  #  WORKS

   adding: Subfolder A/File.txt (deflated 59%)
   adding: Subfolder B/File.txt (deflated 59%)

$ cat FilePaths.txt | zip Test.zip -@  #  WORKS

   updating: Subfolder A/File.txt (deflated 59%)
   updating: Subfolder B/File.txt (deflated 59%)

$ zip Test.zip -@ FilePaths.txt  # DOESN'T WORK

   Waits for keyboard input!
```

Since this information comes from a previously posted question, I'm wondering whether this question should be deleted, or whether it provides enough confirmation testing value to keep.

Comment: Doh!  My brain was messed up.  I was actually planning to post this to the Unix Stack Exchange.  Since someone was kind enough migrate it here, let's see whether someone can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use file lists option:

```
zip ... -@ filelist.txt ...
```

Edit: yes, it depends on the operating system, where on each it is different for zip. So you should use:

```
zip archive -@ < filelist.txt
```

where between `-@` you can put other options.

The `<` will take input from following file and give it to zip.

Comment: I found that the `-@` switch only tells zip to read from `stdin`.  One still needs to feed the contents of `filelist.txt` to `stdin`.  I've added my tests to my originally posted question.  I'm wondering, however, whether to take down the question, as it refers to the code patterns from a previously posted question.